# How do I persist to disk a temporary file using Python?

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am attempting to use the 'tempfile' module for manipulating and creating text files. Once the file is ready I want to save it to disk. I thought it would be as simple as using 'shutil.copy'. However, I get a 'permission denied' IOError:

```
>>> import tempfile, shutil
>>> f = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode ='w+t')
>>> f.write('foo')
>>> shutil.copy(f.name, 'bar.txt')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    shutil.copy(f.name, 'bar.txt')
  File "C:\Python25\lib\shutil.py", line 80, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\shutil.py", line 46, in copyfile
    fsrc = open(src, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\docume~1\\me\\locals~1\\temp\\tmpvqq3go'
>>>
```

Is this not intended when using the 'tempfile' library? Is there a better way to do this? (Maybe I am overlooking something very trivial)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The file you create with `TemporaryFile` or `NamedTemporaryFile` is automatically removed when it's closed, which is why you get an error. If you don't want this, you can use `mkstemp` instead (see the docs for [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp)).

```
>>> import tempfile, shutil, os
>>> fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp()
>>> os.write(fd, 'foo')
>>> os.close(fd)
>>> shutil.copy(path, 'bar.txt')
>>> os.remove(path)
```

Comment: i think the error comes from the fact that you cannot access the file a second time while it is still open (this is only so on windows, according to the documentation)

Comment: Kay Z has a correct answer below.  Plus, s/he explains it better.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is insightful because it gives me to know how to make a temporary directory without it being deleted when the with/as statement is over, seeing as `mkdtemp` works a lot like `mkstemp`.

Comment: `TemporaryFile` opens the file handle, and `shutil` tries to open the file a second time for writing, which [does not work on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23212515/1174169), as @hop points out.

Comment: This is not the reason, can you edit your answer to be correct?

Answer (score 45):

hop is right, and dF. is incorrect on why the error occurs.

Since you haven't called `f.close()` yet, the file is **not** removed.

The [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) for `NamedTemporaryFile` says:

> Whether the name can be used to open the file a second time, while the named temporary file is still open, varies across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows NT or later).

And for `TemporaryFile`:

> Under Unix, the directory entry for the file is removed immediately after the file is created. Other platforms do not support this; your code should not rely on a temporary file created using this function having or not having a visible name in the file system.

Therefore, to persist a temporary file (on Windows), you can do the following:

```
import tempfile, shutil
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+t', delete=False)
f.write('foo')
file_name = f.name
f.close()
shutil.copy(file_name, 'bar.txt')
os.remove(file_name)
```

The solution Hans Sjunnesson provided is also off, because `copyfileobj` only copies from file-like object to file-like object, not file name:

> shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst[, length])
>
> > Copy the contents of the file-like object fsrc to the file-like object fdst. The integer length, if given, is the buffer size. In particular, a negative length value means to copy the data without looping over the source data in chunks; by default the data is read in chunks to avoid uncontrolled memory consumption. Note that if the current file position of the fsrc object is not 0, only the contents from the current file position to the end of the file will be copied.

Comment: @jedierikb `os.remove` will work -- or you can just close the `NamedTemporaryFile` after "all done" without `delete=False`.

Comment: @KayZhu except that without `delete=False`, `shutil.copy` won't work, resulting in the original `IOError` that started this thread! so in this case I agree with @jedierikb, you need the `os.remove`.

Comment: Additionally, the object returned from `NamedTemporaryFile` is a file-like object, so it *could* be used with `shutil.copyfileobj`.

Answer (score 14):

Starting from python 2.6 you can also use `NamedTemporaryFile` with the `delete=` option set to False. This way the temporary file will be accessible, even after you close it.

Note that on Windows (NT and later) you cannot access the file a second time while it is still open. You have to close it before you can copy it. This is not true on Unix systems.

Comment: Shutil works if delete=False is set. However, os.replace or os.rename still won't work

Answer (score 6):

You could always use *shutil.copyfileobj*, in your example:

```
new_file = open('bar.txt', 'rw')
shutil.copyfileobj(f, new_file)
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, but one remark: you probably have to add 'f.seek(0)' first.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how the 'rw' mode is different from 'r+' and 'w+'? Actualy I can't use it, I get a `ValueError` with message that it `must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode`...

Comment: Jyrrka: Wow, this is a blast from the past! If you check out the documentation for `open()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open
Then you see that modes differ in whether they truncate the file or not.

Comment: yep, `rw` seems like an invalid mode in Python 3, what was your intention with `rw`? (would not `w` be enough?)

Comment: @HansSjunnesson yep, rw seems like an invalid mode in Python 3, what was your intention with rw? would not some w version be enough? **`wb`** worked for me :)