# Quick way to save a python TempFile?

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am using `tempfile.TemporaryFile` for some intermediate processing.  The program nicely removes the temp file for me when it closes, which is precisely the behaviour that I want the majority of the time.  But is there a way to save the file for examination in the event of a (trapped) error or other abnormal circumstance?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/94153

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seek to the beginning and use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to copy the data to a file you create.

Answer (score 3):

Use `tempfile.mkstemp()`.  According to the documentation:

> Unlike TemporaryFile(), the user of mkstemp() is responsible for deleting the temporary file when done with it.

Read more [here](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp).

Comment: "which is precisely the behaviour that I want the majority of the time"

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like this would work, but it seems to add a lot more complexity compared with shutil.copyfileobj()