# Rename python tempfile

Tags: python

What is the way  to rename the following tempfile

```
pdf = render_me_some_pdf() #PDF RENDER
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
f.write(pdf)
f.flush()
```

I read somethings about os.rename but I don't really now how to apply it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I persist to disk a temporary file using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94153/how-do-i-persist-to-disk-a-temporary-file-using-python)

Comment: how is this a duplicate? it's entirely different question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the filename via `f.name`. However, unless you use `delete=False` python will (try to) delete the temporary file automatically as soon as it is closed. Disabling auto deletion will keep the tempfile even if you do not save it - so that's not such a good idea.

The best way is *copying* the file and letting python delete the temporary one when it's closed:

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(f.name, 'new-name')
```

Comment: Looking good. What if i want to attach the templile in an email    email.attach_file(f.name)

Comment: @iAmTheOneAndOnly I don't know about `email.attach_file()`, but if there is also a version without `_file`, you maybe can omit the file generation altogether and just do a `email.attach(pdf)` on order to attach the PDF data itself.

Comment: @ThiefMaster doesn't `shutil.copy` create a new file that then won't be deleted, more or less nullifying the use of a temporary file?

Comment: This solution also loses the atomicity of the rename. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873723/is-pythons-shutil-copyfile-atomic

Comment: More detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/94153

Answer (score 39):

> The best way is copying the file and letting python delete the temporary one when it's closed:

I actually think you would be better off using `os.link`:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=os.path.dirname(actual_name)) as f:
  f.write(pdf)
  os.link(f.name, actual_name)
```

This uses `os.link` to create a hard link to the temporary file, which
will persist after the temporary file is automatically deleted.

This code has several advantages:

- We're using the `tempfile` object as a context manager, so we don't
  need to worry about closing it explicitly.
- Since we're creating a hardlink to the file, rather than copying it,
  we don't need to worry about disk space or time consumption due to
  copying a large file.
- Since we're not copying the data, we don't need to call `f.flush()`.
  The file will be flushed automatically when it's closed.

Comment: There is a limitation: In Unix/Linux hard links are only allowed on the same file system.

Comment: @spatar this is dealt with by specifying the `dir` parameter and putting the file in the same directory you want the end file to be in.  This way there is no attempt to link across file systems.

Comment: Limitation: this can't be used to overwrite an existing file, and will instead fail with EEXIST

Comment: @Feline It doesn't, actually: this is a pretty common thing to do. You create a temporary file, send your output to it, etc, and only if everything works do you rename it to the final destination. If you encounter some sort of error, you just abort and delete the tempfile. There are a lot of tools that work exactly like this.

Comment: It is worth noting that this does not work on macOS. Per `man 2 link`: `link() will fail and no link will be created if: ... [EEXIST] The link named by path2 already exists.`

Comment: In this example, `path2` should not already exist.

Comment: Seems like it might be possible that the write is buffered and the link is created and then something fails before or even after the close and the data is not written.  Seems like the best case would be f.write(pdf); f.flush(); os.fsync(f); os.link(f.name, actual_name) where the tempfile is on same fs.  Then the tempfile will be closed and deleted after the link is created to the fully written tempfile.