# Is python's shutil.copyfile() atomic?

Tags: python, linux, shutil

I'm writing a python script that copies a file using [shutil.copyfile()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) on Linux. During the copying, other processes may be trying to read the file. Is the following sufficient to ensure that an external process doesn't get a corrupted view of the file?

```
os.unlink(dest)
shutil.copyfile(src, dest)
```

That is, is shutil.copyfile() atomic such that other processes cannot read the destination file until after the copy operation is complete?

Comment: It's better to copy to a temp file in the same directory,  then os.rename().  *ix: This way it's atomic, even on NFS.  If a process or processes already had the file open, they'll continue to see the old version, while subsequent open()'s of the file will see the new content.

Answer (score 9):

No, `shutil.copyfile` is not atomic. This is part of the [definition of `shutil.copyfile`:](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/37582f4d90b5/Lib/shutil.py#l83)

```
def copyfile(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True):    
    ...
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
        with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
            copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
```

where [`copyfileobj` is defined like this](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/37582f4d90b5/Lib/shutil.py#l63):

```
def copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, length=16*1024):
    while 1:
        buf = fsrc.read(length)
        if not buf:
            break
        fdst.write(buf)
```

The thread calling `copyfile` could be stopped inside this `while-loop` at which point some other process could try to open the file to be read. It would get a corrupted view of the file.

Answer (score 7):

No, it seems to just [loop, reading and writing 16KB at a time](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/shutil.py?revision=80837&view=markup).

For an atomic copy operation, you should copy the file to a different location on the same filesystem, and then `os.rename()` it to the desired location (which *is* guaranteed to be atomic on Linux).