# Installing Scraperwiki for Python generates an error pdftohtml not found

Tags: python, poppler, scraperwiki, pdf-to-html

I have been trying to install Scraperwiki module for Python. However, it generates the error:

*""UserWarning: Local Scraperlibs requires pdftohtml, but pdftohtml was not found in the PATH. You probably need to install it"*.

I looked into poppler as they have pdftohtml file but I don't know how it works - whether there is a python library I need to install or a .exe file. And how do I go about installing it. Running on Windows.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not intending to use `scraperwiki.pdftoxml()`, then the warning doesn't apply. It doesn't stop you from installing the `scraperwiki` package, however.

Also, that function doesn't work on Windows at all as is; it uses `NamedTemporaryFiles` which behave [differently on Windows to Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94153/how-do-i-persist-to-disk-a-temporary-file-using-python/#9155528).

If you **do** want to use that function, the simplest way to get an up-to-date version of `pdftohtml` on Windows is to download [Calibre Portable](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_portable). (The version on Sourceforge is older.)

Install it anywhere; you just need a few files from it. From where you installed it, from the folder containing calibre.exe, you need `pdftohtml.exe` into your working folder as well as, from the `DLLs` folder in the Calibre install, `freetype.dll`, `jpeg.dll`, `libpng12.dll`, `zlib1.dll`.

You'll also need code based on `scraperwiki.pdftoxml()` instead, like:

```py
def pdftoxml(pdfdata, options):
    """converts pdf file to xml file"""
    # lots of hacky Windows fixes c.f. original
    with open('input.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pdfdata)
    cmd = 'pdftohtml -xml -nodrm -zoom 1.5 -enc UTF-8 -noframes '
    if options:
        cmd += options
    cmd += 'input.pdf output.xml'
    cmd = cmd + " > NUL 2>&1"
    os.system(cmd)
    with open('output.xml', 'r') as f:
    return f.read()
```

(I was trying to get this working for a user in Windows recently; I'll keep the [gist](https://gist.github.com/StevenMaude/88def892b0cbfa8ae818) containing this code updated.)